# Fall Steeply Away

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

For most intransitive verb phrases consisting a verb and a (main) adverb, any extra complementary adverbs should go before the verb or after the main adverb, not between the verb and main adverb.   For example, sentences 1 & 2:

> 1. They ***quickly went away*** on a vacation.
> 2. "They ***went away quickly*** on a vacation.

are standard, and sentence 3:

> 3. They ***went quickly away*** on a vacation.

is not standard.

But then, I saw [this](http://www.nytimes.com/1991/09/21/nyregion/no-name-few-clues-the-case-of-baby-hope.html?pagewanted=all):

> Beyond the right-hand shoulder of the road, just north of the Dyckman Street exit, the land ***falls steeply away*** to the Hudson River.

The intransitive phrasal verb "***fall away***" means to slope downward.  But, is "*fall* **steeply** *away*", with "*steeply*" sandwiched between "*fall*" and "*away*", a little awkward?  Would "**steeply** *falls away*" or "*falls away* **steeply**" be better?

Comment: You're correct in noting that it's best not to separate the components of a phrasal verb. Mr Blumethal made a choice based on _style_ here. To him, _the land falls steeply away to the Hudson River_ sounds more rhythmical, more musical, than _the land falls away steeply to the Hudson River._ Most writers are more concerned with style than form, and I wager Mr Blumethal didn't think for one moment about preserving the integrity of the phrasal _fall away._

Comment: The phrasal integrity is not disturbed by the separation, and  **away to the Hudson** is preferable to **steeply to the Hudson**.